# Minimum requirements to use Indefero + SVN

Tags: apache, svn, indefero

Hey everyone, I made sure there wasn't a similar discussion before posting but forgive me if I am mistaken.

Question: Can I use Indefero - http://www.indefero.net/ - with SVN on a linux server if I do not have any sort of web interface installed for Apache?  Instead, I want to use Indefero with SVN by just using the svnserve server.  From my readings, I'm not finding this exact situation mentioned anywhere, so I'm doubting if this configuration is possible.

Forgive my ignorance; Thanks. :)

EDIT: the svnserve server and Indefero installation will be running on the same machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnucom, at the moment it is not yet in the master branch, but you already have a [patch to fully support svnserve](http://code.mjdsystems.ca/p/indefero-patches/source/tree/master/SyncScms). If you do not want to apply the patch, you can also use Indefero without it controlling the access rights to the repositories. Indefero can read the repositories and you control the access to the source yourself. You can get a lot of your questions [answered by the community](http://indefero.net/open-source/) if you need.

Comment: Thank you Loic, I ended up installing mod_dav, and have Indefero set up nicely.  Really great software, I'll search the community page next time. :)